# Add event to Multi-Bloc Provider initialization not working

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

I wanted to add event when initializing bloc inside the 'main.dart'.
But It didn't call init event . Are there any way to do this without calling inside 'initState'  of the next class

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (context) => CountlyBloc()..add(CountlyInitEvent()))
    ], child: MyApp()),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

BHARATH T 's answer is almost correct but you have to set `lazy` to false not `true`. Since `true` means you DO want it to be created lazy. The rest is correct

Answer (score 0):

`MultiBlocProvider( providers: [ BlocProvider(create: (context) => CountlyBloc()..add(CountlyInitEvent()),lazy:false,) ], child: MyApp()),`

in order to initialize the bloc instance immediately

Answer (score -1):

Just set `lazy` param inside the `BlocProvider` as true. By default, the bloc is instantiated only when it is used first. Setting the lazy param to true, forces it to instantiate at the moment.

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(providers: [
      BlocProvider(create: (context) => CountlyBloc()..add(CountlyInitEvent()),lazy:false,)
    ], child: MyApp()),
  );
}
```

Hope it helps! Happy coding:)